# How to create custom AnimatedIcon - Flutter

Tags: flutter, icons

I know that icon use [AnimatedIcon](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AnimatedIcons-class.html) from Flutter package. But the available icons doesn't fit my needs. What i want is to build/draw my own AninimatedIcon (from default IconData or not). Is there any way to achieve this?

Please see an example [Here](https://storage.googleapis.com/spec-host/mio-staging%2Fmio-design%2F1566239436131%2Fassets%2F1HcTiqNmmbOf81hudToN_5g2BR0BICetQ%2F02-owl-icons.mp4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

used flare for icon animation https://www.2dimensions.com/

Answer (score 2):

Just add the [plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/animated_icon_button), set the dependencies, imports and use it like this:

```
AnimateIcons(
startIcon: Icons.add,
endIcon: Icons.close,
size: 60.0,
onStartIconPress: () {
    print("Clicked on Add Icon");
},
onEndIconPress: () {
    print("Clicked on Close Icon");
},
duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
clockwise: false,
```

),